# inspect values of an array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

What will be the most efficient way to verify if contents of an array are just repetitions of the same value?

I am reading from an input stream into an array for a lookup:

```
keysz=new byte[sz];
            while((c=bis.read(keysz,pos,sz))>0){
            if(keysz contains all zeroes) break;
                    pos+=sz;
                    dec.write(hm.get(keysz.toString()));
            }
```

However,if the array consists of all zeroes ('0000') in an iteration, I need to break out.
Note that the size of the array will be dynamic.

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE Example](http://sscce.org/)? With this part of code is not so easy to understand what `bis` is and what the `read()` function do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the value that's supposed to be repeated you can do this:

```
public boolean allRepetitions (Byte[] array, Byte value){
       return Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), value) == array.length;
    }
```

Otherwise, you can use a Set to check if all elements are repeated:

```
public boolean allRepetitions (Byte[] array){
       return new HashSet<Byte>(Arrays.asList(array)).size() == 1;
    }
```

You'd need to use Byte[] instead of byte[] to convert it to a List

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsAllZero(byte[] myArr)
{  
    while(int i=0; i<myArr.length; i++)
    {
        if(myArr[i] != 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Check that all elements of arr equal val */
public static boolean allEqualTo(byte[] arr, byte val) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] != val) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/* Check that all elements of arr have the same value */
public static boolean allSame(byte[] arr) {
  if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return allEqualTo(arr, arr[0]);
}
```